# $(\mathbb R^{\times},\cdot)$ isn't isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I'm trying to prove the real numbers with addition isn't ismorphic to the same real numbers without 0 and with multiplication.

I've tried a lot without success. My strategy is show a contradiction from an isomorphism between them.

I need belp

Thanks

Comment: Interestingly, even though $(R, \cdot)$ is not isomorphic to $(R, +)$, $(R^{+}, \cdot)$ is isomorphic to $(R, +)$ via the exponential map.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh indeed!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $f:(\mathbb R^{\times},\cdot)\rightarrow(\mathbb R,+)$ is an isomorphism, then
$$0=f(1)=f((-1)(-1))=f(-1)+f(-1)=2f(-1)\implies f(-1)=0$$
which is impossible since $f$ is $1-1$ and already $f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to see this: not every element is a square in $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$. But every element in $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is the sum of two equal elements.